# Moving pointer to vector of vectors to specific position

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a `maze` vector of vector of ints and a pointer `line` to that vector declared as follows. I also have a pointer to `line` that identifies each element in particular.

```
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> maze;
    auto * line = new std::vector<std::vector<int>>(maze); //pointer to maze to hold line position
    auto * column = line; // pointer to element in line
```

`maze` is a vector of vectors of int that holds numbers. I'm supposed to follow a route starting from 1 and going to the next highest number(+1) until i find an exit or a dead end inside the labyrinth.

It is unclear to me how the pointer `line` works. My understanding is that it will hold the address of the first element in the first vector of `maze`. By writing `line+1`, the pointer will hold the address of the first element of the second vector etc. The compiler lets me write `column = &line[1]` and i assume `column` will point to the first element of `line[1]`.

However, i didn't find a way to have `line` point to a specific vector in `maze`. I have tried the following and all cause errors:

```
line = &maze[i]; // make line point to i-th vector in maze
line = &(*maze.begin()); // as suggested in a stackoverflow topic, converting iterator to pointer
*line = maze[i];
```

The only way i didn't get an error was by writing `line->begin = maze.begin()`, but i want to move `line` to any position in `maze`.

What is the conceptual difference that doesn't allow me to assign `line` the same way i do `column`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is unclear to me how the pointer line works.

This line

```
auto * line = new std::vector<std::vector<int>>(maze);
```

creates a fresh new instance of `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, copying the contents of `maze` into that new instance, and then stores a pointer to the new instance in `line`. `line` is not a pointer to `maze`!  That would be this instead:

```
auto * line = &maze;
```

> By writing line+1, the pointer will hold the address of the first element of the second vector etc.

No. `line` is not a pointer to an array, or to an element of an array, so you cannot increment it (well, to be precise, it can be considered as an array with one element, and so incrementing the pointer once is fine, but anything beyond that is not).

> The only way i didn't get an error was by writing line->begin = maze.begin()

I'll skip the rest, because you are on the wrong track, and I have to admit that I do not completely understand what the second snippet is supposed to do.

> However, i didn't find a way to have line point to a specific vector in maze

It is unclear why you want a pointer in the first place. An element of `maze` you get via

```
auto x = maze[i][j];
```

a reference via

```
auto& r = maze[i][j];
```

and a pointer via

```
auto* p = &maze[i][j];
```

It is not perfectly clear what you are trying to accomplish. What is clear is that your attempt with using `line` is flawed, because it is not a pointer to `maze`.

PS: If your intention was to use pointer arithmetic to navigate through the `maze`, then there is bad news: It won't work. At least not as easy as you hope for. A `std::vector<T>` stores its elements in contiguous memory. However, that memory is not inside the `vector` object. Hence, the `T`s in a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` are stored in contiguous blocks, but they are not contiguous as a whole.  The outer `vector` holds a contiguous block of `vector<T>`s, and each inner `vector<T>` holds a separate contiguous block of `int`s.  Collectively, the individual blocks of `int`s are scattered around memory.

Comment: thank you for this explanation, it makes a lot more sense now. i wanted to use pointers to practice them better. i figured it'll be easier using [] operator but i wanted to try something else

Comment: @xampierre the most important skill you need to learn about raw pointers is to not use them. Seriously. Even less you should use `new` to create objects. And you almost never want to dynamically create a standard container.

Comment: @xampierre I would not say "whenever possible", but when you need a pointer then almost always you should use a smart pointer.